# Add delay when index++ (increase)

Tags: javascript

I created a type writer effect with JavaScript but I would like when the word change add delay before the function increase index

```js
const texts = ["Front Developer", "Designer", "Human"];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = '';
let letter = '';

(function type(){
    if(count === texts.length){
        count = 0;
    }
    currentText =  texts[count];
    letter = currentText.slice(0, index++);

    document.querySelector('.typing').textContent = letter;
    if(letter.length === currentText.length){
        count++;
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(type, 400);
}());
```

```html
<span>I'm <span class="typing"></span></span>
```

Comment: Why not set `400` as a variable and add some amount to it in the second `if` statement? Alternatively, use an `else` and use a different `setTimeout` call in each branch. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `return` with different `timeout`

```js
const texts = ["Front Developer", "Designer", "Human"];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = '';
let letter = '';

(function type() {
  if (count === texts.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  currentText = texts[count];
  letter = currentText.slice(0, index++);

  document.querySelector('.typing').textContent = letter;
  if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
    count++;
    index = 0;
    setTimeout(type, 2000);
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(type, 200);
}());
```

```html
<span>I'm <span class="typing"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `async / await`

```js
const texts = ["Front Developer", "Designer", "Human"];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = '';
let letter = '';

(async function type(){
    if(count === texts.length){
        count = 0;
    }
    currentText =  texts[count];
    letter = currentText.slice(0, index++);

    document.querySelector('.typing').textContent = letter;
    if(letter.length === currentText.length){
        count++;
        index = 0;
        await sleep(4000);
    }
    await sleep(30);
    type();
}());

function sleep(time) { return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time))}
```

```html
<span>I'm <span class="typing"></span></span>
```